# Convert string to array or object

Tags: javascript, arrays

is there possible to convert this string to array or object? It is not a valid stringify JSON data, not sure how to tackle this.

```
"{"subject":"Test Comment"},{"message":"Test Message."}"
```

Thank in advance!

Comment: Although I'm sure you'll get answers on how to hack around it below, the best choice will always be to fix it at source - where it is generated

Comment: possible duplicate of [Best way to convert string to array of object in javascript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3473639/best-way-to-convert-string-to-array-of-object-in-javascript)

Comment: @Paul S. Actually, I am pulling out the data from a LMS service using the API provided which I can't go in and modify the source, what I can do is modify it once I get the data populated on my side.

Comment: @vjdhama I actually tried the solution on this thread before but it din't solve my problem though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like this:

```
JSON.parse('[' + '{"subject":"Test Comment"},{"message":"Test Message."}' + ']')
```