# how to use Javascript variable into google charts

Tags: javascript, arrays, variables, charts

When I add:

```
    var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable
        ([
['Hora', 'Mínima',{type: 'string', role: 'style'},{type: 'string', role: 'annotation'}, 'Média',{type: 'string', role: 'style'},{type: 'string', role: 'annotation'}, 'Máxima',{type: 'string', role: 'style'},{type: 'string', role: 'annotation'}],['14:50', 0.0,'point { size: 3; shape-type: circle; fill-color: #33CC00','0.0',0.8,'point { size: 3; shape-type: circle; fill-color: #33CC00','NE (0.8)', 4.0,'point { size: 3; shape-type: circle; fill-color: #33CC00','4.0'],['15:00', 0.0,'point { size: 3; shape-type: circle; fill-color: #33CC00','0.0',2.6,'point { size: 3; shape-type: circle; fill-color: #33CC00','SE (2.6)', 6.7,'point { size: 3; shape-type: circle; fill-color: #33CC00','6.7'],['15:10', 0.0,'point { size: 3; shape-type: circle; fill-color: #33CC00','0.0',5.5,'point { size: 3; shape-type: circle; fill-color: #33CC00','SE (5.5)', 10.2,'point { size: 3; shape-type: circle; fill-color: #FFCC00','10.2'],['15:20', 2.2,'point { size: 3; shape-type: circle; fill-color: #33CC00','2.2',73,'point { size: 3; shape-type: circle; fill-color: #33CC00','SE (7.3)', 11.8,'point { size: 3; shape-type: circle; fill-color: #FFCC00','11.8'],['15:30', 2.8,'point { size: 3; shape-type: circle; fill-color: #33CC00','2.8',7.7,'point { size: 3; shape-type: circle; fill-color: #33CC00','SE (7.7)', 11.8,'point { size: 3; shape-type: circle; fill-color: #FFCC00','11.8'],['15:40', 3.8,'point { size: 3; shape-type: circle; fill-color: #33CC00','3.8',7.0,'point { size: 3; shape-type: circle; fill-color: #33CC00','SE (7.0)', 10.2,'point { size: 3; shape-type: circle; fill-color: #FFCC00','10.2'],['15:50', 5.7,'point { size: 3; shape-type: circle; fill-color: #33CC00','5.7',8.4,'point { size: 3; shape-type: circle; fill-color: #33CC00','SE (8.4)', 13.0,'point { size: 3; shape-type: circle; fill-color: #FFCC00','13.0']
        ]);
```

it works fine, but when i set this value into a variable doesn't work.

Like:

```
var vvalor_inserir = "['Hora', 'Mínima',{type: 'string', role: 'style'},{type: 'string', role: 'annotation'}, 'Média',{type: 'string', role: 'style'},{type: 'string', role: 'annotation'}, 'Máxima',{type: 'string', role: 'style'},{type: 'string', role: 'annotation'}],['14:50', 0.0,'point { size: 3; shape-type: circle; fill-color: #33CC00','0.0',0.8,'point { size: 3; shape-type: circle; fill-color: #33CC00','NE (0.8)', 4.0,'point { size: 3; shape-type: circle; fill-color: #33CC00','4.0'],['15:00', 0.0,'point { size: 3; shape-type: circle; fill-color: #33CC00','0.0',2.6,'point { size: 3; shape-type: circle; fill-color: #33CC00','SE (2.6)', 6.7,'point { size: 3; shape-type: circle; fill-color: #33CC00','6.7'],['15:10', 0.0,'point { size: 3; shape-type: circle; fill-color: #33CC00','0.0',5.5,'point { size: 3; shape-type: circle; fill-color: #33CC00','SE (5.5)', 10.2,'point { size: 3; shape-type: circle; fill-color: #FFCC00','10.2'],['15:20', 2.2,'point { size: 3; shape-type: circle; fill-color: #33CC00','2.2',7   3,'point { size: 3; shape-type: circle; fill-color: #33CC00','SE (7.3)', 11.8,'point { size: 3; shape-type: circle; fill-color: #FFCC00','11.8'],['15:30', 2.8,'point { size: 3; shape-type: circle; fill-color: #33CC00','2.8',7.7,'point { size: 3; shape-type: circle; fill-color: #33CC00','SE (7.7)', 11.8,'point { size: 3; shape-type: circle; fill-color: #FFCC00','11.8'],['15:40', 3.8,'point { size: 3; shape-type: circle; fill-color: #33CC00','3.8',7.0,'point { size: 3; shape-type: circle; fill-color: #33CC00','SE (7.0)', 10.2,'point { size: 3; shape-type: circle; fill-color: #FFCC00','10.2'],['15:50', 5.7,'point { size: 3; shape-type: circle; fill-color: #33CC00','5.7',8.4,'point { size: 3; shape-type: circle; fill-color: #33CC00','SE (8.4)', 13.0,'point { size: 3; shape-type: circle; fill-color: #FFCC00','13.0']";

    var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable
    ([
    vvalor_inserir
    ]);
```

Any idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's because you're saving the value as a string, when in fact you need to save it as an array. The method `google.visualization.arrayToDataTable()` receives an array of values, which is denoted by encapsulating said values in square brackets. When you wrap these values in quotes, it no longer treats them as a series of values, and instead just provides the string of characters.

Additionally,the outside pair of square brackets cannot be left in the method call, and must be kept as a part of the variable (to make it an array, not just a handful of comma-separated objects).

This should work:

```
var vvalor_inserir = [['Hora', 'Mínima',{type: 'string', role: 'style'},{type: 'string', role: 'annotation'}, 'Média',{type: 'string', role: 'style'},{type: 'string', role: 'annotation'}, 'Máxima',{type: 'string', role: 'style'},{type: 'string', role: 'annotation'}],['14:50', 0.0,'point { size: 3; shape-type: circle; fill-color: #33CC00','0.0',0.8,'point { size: 3; shape-type: circle; fill-color: #33CC00','NE (0.8)', 4.0,'point { size: 3; shape-type: circle; fill-color: #33CC00','4.0'],['15:00', 0.0,'point { size: 3; shape-type: circle; fill-color: #33CC00','0.0',2.6,'point { size: 3; shape-type: circle; fill-color: #33CC00','SE (2.6)', 6.7,'point { size: 3; shape-type: circle; fill-color: #33CC00','6.7'],['15:10', 0.0,'point { size: 3; shape-type: circle; fill-color: #33CC00','0.0',5.5,'point { size: 3; shape-type: circle; fill-color: #33CC00','SE (5.5)', 10.2,'point { size: 3; shape-type: circle; fill-color: #FFCC00','10.2'],['15:20', 2.2,'point { size: 3; shape-type: circle; fill-color: #33CC00','2.2',73,'point { size: 3; shape-type: circle; fill-color: #33CC00','SE (7.3)', 11.8,'point { size: 3; shape-type: circle; fill-color: #FFCC00','11.8'],['15:30', 2.8,'point { size: 3; shape-type: circle; fill-color: #33CC00','2.8',7.7,'point { size: 3; shape-type: circle; fill-color: #33CC00','SE (7.7)', 11.8,'point { size: 3; shape-type: circle; fill-color: #FFCC00','11.8'],['15:40', 3.8,'point { size: 3; shape-type: circle; fill-color: #33CC00','3.8',7.0,'point { size: 3; shape-type: circle; fill-color: #33CC00','SE (7.0)', 10.2,'point { size: 3; shape-type: circle; fill-color: #FFCC00','10.2'],['15:50', 5.7,'point { size: 3; shape-type: circle; fill-color: #33CC00','5.7',8.4,'point { size: 3; shape-type: circle; fill-color: #33CC00','SE (8.4)', 13.0,'point { size: 3; shape-type: circle; fill-color: #FFCC00','13.0']];

var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable
(
vvalor_inserir
);
```

**Side Note:**

On an unrelated note, it's not normally conventional to break a method call across multiple lines like this:

```
var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable
(
vvalor_inserir
);
```

You normally see this done if you're passing a large data structure explicitly (as was the case in your initial example), but stylistically it's probably better practice to simply write it like this:

```
var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable( vvalor_inserir );
```

That is, however, only a nitpick, and irrelevant to the functionality of your code.

Comment: Hi... just did as you said but still errors...

I think because multiple "[" and "]"  at the same array on variable..?
Maybe I'm passing to vvalor_inserir variable multiples "[" and "]" comma delimited?

Comment: @Rodrigo - Ah, my apologies, I didn't look closely enough at the variable itself. The second square brackets weren't redundant, and there was some slightly-incorrect syntax in the object itself. I have edited my answer above. Could you try again, and share your results? I have confirmed in my testing that the variable `vvalor_inserir` at least is now in a valid format.

Comment: Hi.. Absolutelly I will.... One last question.. how to convert to this array format from a Sring variable? Like...

var string =  "[['Hora', 'Mínima',{type: 'string', role: 'style'},{type: 'string', role: 'annotation'}, 'Média',{type: 'string', role: 'style'},{type: 'string', role: 'annotation'}, 'Máxima',{type: 'string', role: 'style'},{type: 'string', role: 'annotation'}]"......

Need to convert a String to this array variable

Comment: There are quite a lot of questions about this sort of thing (such as http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3473639/best-way-to-convert-string-to-array-of-object-in-javascript), but in your case you're working with a fairly large set of data, and it's not properly formatted to be parsed via JSON. I think the best way to address this would be to open a question explaining the form in which you receive this information and the necessary output form, since now your problem is "how do I turn a string into an array of arrays and objects."