# Convert string Array to Object Array in javascript

Tags: javascript

I am having the below array

```
const a1 = [1,2,3];
```

and want to convert it into

```
const b1 = [{id:1},{id:2},{id:3}];
```

Is there a quick way in doing in javascript

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map

Comment: This [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3473639/best-way-to-convert-string-to-array-of-object-in-javascript) has the answer you expect

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [Array.map()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)

```js
const a1 = [1,2,3];
const b1 = a1.map(val => ({id: val}));
console.log(b1);
```

Comment: A question that is solvable by a 5 second search? Imho -> Yes. That question shouldn't exist in the first place and doesn't deserve an answer other than a close vote (needs details or as duplicate because this will then definitely have been asked and answered before)